# Merging like teams into one row while creating new columns from one column

Tags: merge

I currently have data for multiple teams (which always have the same team number and team group) with several different Identifiers. The data typically has around around 3,000-5,000 rows, with approximately 1,000 Teams.

| Team Name | Team No | Team Group | Identifier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 962990 | 00000001 | Monthly |
| Red | 962990 | 00000001 | Migration |
| Orange | 983456 | 00000001 | Product |
| Orange | 983456 | 00000001 | Migration |
| Yellow | 123589 | 00000002 | Monthly |
| Yellow | 123589 | 00000002 | Product |
| Green | 438999 | 00000001 | Monthly |
| Green | 438999 | 00000001 | Product |

I would like to merge the data together with one row per team, while creating new column headers with the Identifiers and have the information under the header either blank or entered in as an "X".

| Team Name | Team No | Team Group | Monthly | Migration | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 962990 | 00000001 | X | X |  |
| Orange | 983456 | 00000001 |  | X | X |
| Yellow | 123589 | 00000002 | X |  | X |
| Green | 438999 | 00000001 | X |  | X |

I know the answer lies somewhere in PIVOT/Conditional Aggregation, but I’m coming up with either severely skewed results or errors. Even when I'm able to appropriately get the column herders set up, I can't get the data to line up appropriately under those headers.